# positioning divs with unknown width

Tags: html, css

I have container, and two divs inside lets call it `left` and `right`.

So now my problem is that in left i have some text so and i can't set width, and i need my right div to be 100% width but in the same line as left div, it's kinda hard to explain, i have my example here, http://jsfiddle.net/CeKvT/ as you can see the right green block is under the left blue div how can i move it to the same line as the left one?

Comment: Do you want "left" to be on top of "right" or do you want them to be side by side?

Comment: @JoseAntonio: The intention is to set the divs side-by-side and not over one-another, as I understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is http://oocss.org/. I have this example jsFiddle to show you how http://jsfiddle.net/k765B/

Oh, and an advice: don't use `outline`, use `border` instead, because browsers work differently with it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to accomplish this using only CSS, but here is a simple JQuery code to resize the div correctly to "fill" the space on a single line.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#right").width($("#container").outerWidth() - $("#left").width());
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need to do is set the left div to `float:left;` and the right div to `float:right;` inside the container. In this way, the divs will automatically adjust to the widths of their content.

But the solution comes with a caveat: In case you type a paragraph, for example, in the left div without hitting a carriage return, the right div would go on shrinking as the left div expands to the length of it's content. The vice-versa is also true. All the best.